# Issue with CardView and OnClickListener in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am using CardView layout as Row for RecyclerView. However I am facing issue in attaching OnClickListener to the layout.
I am using following layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/unit_5"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/unit_5">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/spinnerWidth"
        android:background="@drawable/row_item_background"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/dialog_left_padding">

<!-- Other items -->

        </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Following are my adapter and ViewHolder

```
 private class SampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SampleViewHolder> {
        ArrayList<Item> arrayList;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            arrayList.addAll(items);
        }

        @Override
        public SampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, parent, false);
            SampleViewHolder holder = new SampleViewHolder(view);
            holder.setClickHandler(handler);
            return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(SampleViewHolder holder, int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return arrayList.size();
        }

    }

  static class SampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
        TextView name;
        IClickHandler clickHandler;
        public IClickHandler getClickHandler() {
            return clickHandler;
        }

        public void setClickHandler(IClickHandler clickHandler) {
            this.clickHandler = clickHandler;
        }

        public SampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView
                    .findViewById(R.id.name);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (getClickHandler() != null) {
                getClickHandler().onItemClicked(view, getLayoutPosition());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            if (getClickHandler() != null) {
                getClickHandler().onItemLongClicked(view, getLayoutPosition());
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

But this onClick is never fired.

However, if I replace CardView with LinearLayout every thing works fine.
I am not sure what is the issue here. Can somebody help me in this?

Thanks.

Comment: Post the complete adapter and the code that used to initialize the recyclerView and the setting of the listener.

Comment: Sorry, this is beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 7):

Actually implementing onClick is very straightforward and I am not sure of the implementation of a custom click handler (IClickHandler).

First of all View holder should be just:

```
static class SampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  TextView name;

  public SampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
  }
}
```

And then in SampleAdapter

```
@Override
public SampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, parent, false);
  SampleViewHolder holder = new SampleViewHolder(view);
  return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Item item = arrayList.get(position);

    holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
         //notice I implemented onClickListener here
         // so I can associate this click with final Item item           
       }

    });

}
```

Comment: yes, it is works for me! in additional i added interface and it is works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Perfect Generic Solution

**Step 1:**Go to xml where the cardview is placed.Assign it a id

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"/>
```

**Step 2:**Inside View holder class get hold of the id of card view

public class View_Holder_For_Grocery extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cv;

```
View_Holder_For_Grocery(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
}
```

}

**Step 3:**Inside Recycler_View_Adapter class the onBindViewHolder method the onClick is as below

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(View_Holder_For_Grocery holder, final int position) {

        holder.cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent0=new Intent(v.getContext(),SunrayActivity.class);
                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent0);
                        break;
                     case 1:
                        Intent intent1=new Intent(v.getContext(),SunfeastActivity.class);
                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Intent intent2=new Intent(v.getContext(),SunriseActivity.class);
                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent2);
                        break;

                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. OnClick didn't seem to work.The problem was the my layout's root view was Relative Layout...So I changed that to card view (and added relative layout inside it) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the way the layout was setup for the row. I made a linear layout as the top most element thus making card view as its child and everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

My recyclerView inside card did not respond when i click,
The issue was Parent Tag of my CardView was ScrollView. In other words my row_layout i.e CardView was inside ScrollView.So i removed the ScrollView it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue .
In my case, the problem was that i had set

```
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
```

**for a relative layout which was inside my Cardview.**

Hence the click listeners on cardview and the whole itemView were not getting triggered.

Wasted 4 hours there.