# How to access RecyclerView viewholder inside main activity in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list in activity with dynamic data.When i click on a button inside list item,I want to hide any text from list item.From adapter class it can be possible to get views from custom layout but from activity how to do this?

Comment: you have to make a listener and implement it on your activity.

Comment: using listener i can be able to get the position but how to get the views with respected position from adapter viewholder inside activity

Comment: You shouldn't access views from your activity.. let your adapter handle that.. use callbacks with flags and notify your adapter whenever a change is performed so That it'll update the displayed list

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284067/handle-button-click-inside-a-row-in-recyclerview#answer-37588931

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle Button click inside a row in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284067/handle-button-click-inside-a-row-in-recyclerview)

Comment: do you want to call a method of adapter form activity?

Comment: i can get the position inside activity but is it possible to get views with the respective position in main activity not in adapter?

Comment: why do you want to change the visibility of adapter contents from your activity, can you explain your scenario

Comment: i have a food list with add to cart button when food is successfully added   want to hide the add to cart button and show the cart quantity

Answer (score 0):

Just change the data of that particular position and then call `YourCustomUpdateFunc`:

```
//Function inside your RecyclerAdapter class
public void YourCustomUpdateFunc(int pos){
    notifyItemChanged(pos);
}
```

Then, the `onBindViewHolder` function will do its work.

Answer (score -1):

```
First Create local Variable in adapter class as

OnCustClick mclickListner;

then in viewholder override method like 

 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mclickListner != null) {
                mclickListner.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }

after that add this methods in your adapter class

 public interface OnCustClick{
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
    public void setOnCustClick(OnCustClick mclickListner)
    {
        this.mclickListner = mclickListner;
    }

and in activity implement interface
```