# buttons and don't get clicked in recyclerview in adapter

Tags: android

I making a list of usernames and call buttons, each username has a call button next to it, when I click the call button the code inside the call button does not get executed in all clicks, I tried to make the whole item clickable so that if the user clicks on the button, the username or any part in the layout_item the code gets executed but no change happened.
Here is how I am implementing the adapter:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.freind_list_item, parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(mView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Friend friend = friends.get(position);
    holder.btnInitCallHandler(friend.getUsername(), friend.get_id());
    holder.setUsername(friend.getUsername());
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView txtUsername;
    Button btnInitCallWithFriend;
    RelativeLayout rlInsteadOfButtonHandler;

    MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtUsername = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_friend_item);
        btnInitCallWithFriend = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnInitCallWithFriendNormal);
        friendState = itemView.findViewById(R.id.onlineState);
        signedAsGlasses = itemView.findViewById(R.id.signedInAsGlasses);
        signedAsLaptop = itemView.findViewById(R.id.signedInAsLaptop);
        rlInsteadOfButtonHandler = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlInsteadButtonHandler);
    }
    void setUsername(String username) {
        txtUsername.setText(username);
    }


    void btnInitCallHandler(String username, String userId) {
        btnInitCallWithFriend.setOnClickListener((view) -> {
            Timber.tag("KingArmstringNormalUserCall").d("normal user call button clicked from the adapter");
            viewAccessor.initCall(username, userId);
        });

        rlInsteadOfButtonHandler.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
            viewAccessor.initCall(username, userId);
        });
    }
}
```

the viewAccessor is just an interface implemented by the activity, and have only one method (initCall)
the initCall(username, userId) in the Activity has only a toast and a log

EDIT:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_friend_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txt_friend_name_placeholder"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlInsteadButtonHandler"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <!--<at.markushi.ui.CircleButton-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/btnInitCallWithFriend"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="70dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="40dp"-->
        <!--android:src="@drawable/ic_video_call"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginStart="10dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_gravity="center"-->
        <!--android:focusable="false"-->
        <!--android:focusableInTouchMode="false"-->
        <!--app:cb_color="#fff"-->
        <!--android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>-->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnInitCallWithFriendNormal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="call" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post the xml of the item

Comment: a second, I will

Comment: done @ArmaniDarknight

Comment: Remove onclick listeners from inside the btnInitCallHandler() method. 
Use getter/setter to pass value to them from activity. Hope this helps

Comment: please can u tell me how to do that, I mean getter and setter @Shrikant

Comment: There are many links out there but you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284067/handle-button-click-inside-a-row-in-recyclerview

Comment: u mean passing the context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out whats happening, I have been handling lots of things in the foreground, I have transferred lots of them to other threads, now it worked, u might don't believe me, but many really experienced people said to me, that they encountered a very similar situations.

Answer (score 1):

use below code on constructor of MyViewHolder class. This code makes an item clickable.

```
itemView.setClickable(true);
```

Also set onClickLiester on MyViewHolder class. Then use getAdapterPostion() method to determine which item clicked.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dataList.get(getAdapterPosition()); //this code will return the clicked item object.
        });
```

Comment: thanks for effort, but this did not help, anyways I gave u the rep up :)

Answer (score 1):

First remove `btnInitCallHandler()` function from your `ViewHolder`, then set the clickListener directly in your viewHolder, you can get the current item from your list by calling `getAdapterPosition()` for exemple:

```
btnInitCallWithFriend.setOnClickListener((view) -> {
            Timber.tag("KingArmstringNormalUserCall").d("normal user call button clicked from the adapter");
            viewAccessor.initCall(friends.get(getAdapterPosition).getUsername(), friends.get(getAdapterPosition).get_id());
        });
```

so this your new adapter class:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.freind_list_item, parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(mView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //do your stuff
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView txtUsername;
    Button btnInitCallWithFriend;
    RelativeLayout rlInsteadOfButtonHandler;

    MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtUsername = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_friend_item);
        btnInitCallWithFriend = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnInitCallWithFriendNormal);
        friendState = itemView.findViewById(R.id.onlineState);
        signedAsGlasses = itemView.findViewById(R.id.signedInAsGlasses);
        signedAsLaptop = itemView.findViewById(R.id.signedInAsLaptop);
        rlInsteadOfButtonHandler = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlInsteadButtonHandler);

        btnInitCallWithFriend.setOnClickListener((view) -> {
            Timber.tag("KingArmstringNormalUserCall").d("normal user call button clicked from the adapter");
            viewAccessor.initCall(friends.get(getAdapterPosition).getUsername(), friends.get(getAdapterPosition).get_id());
        });

        rlInsteadOfButtonHandler.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
            viewAccessor.initCall(friends.get(getAdapterPosition).getUsername(), friends.get(getAdapterPosition).get_id());
        });
    }
    void setUsername(String username) {
        txtUsername.setText(username);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for effort, but did not help, I gave u the rep for effort anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

Following is a simple yet powerful implementation of RecylcerView. Try to read out the basics of recycler view and why viewholder is used. Hope this helps you out.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements TestAdapter.ItemClickListener {

TestAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

    ArrayList<String> testNames = new ArrayList<>();
    testNames.add("Horse");
    testNames.add("Cow");
    testNames.add("Camel");
    testNames.add("Sheep");
    testNames.add("Goat");

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.testList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new TestAdapter(this, testNames);
    adapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + adapter.getItem(position) + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

Following is adapter class implementation

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
private List<String> mData;
private Activity mActivity;

public TestAdapter(TestActivity testActivity, ArrayList<String> testNames) {
    this.mData = testNames;
    this.mActivity = testActivity;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.test_row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(mView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String animal = mData.get(position);
    holder.txtUsername.setText(animal);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public String getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position);
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView txtUsername;
    Button btnInitCallWithFriend;

    MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtUsername = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_friend_item);
        btnInitCallWithFriend = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnInitCallWithFriendNormal);
        //friendState = itemView.findViewById(R.id.onlineState);
        //signedAsGlasses = itemView.findViewById(R.id.signedInAsGlasses);
        //signedAsLaptop = itemView.findViewById(R.id.signedInAsLaptop);

        btnInitCallWithFriend.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "You clicked call " + getAdapterPosition() + " position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mClickListener != null) {
                    mClickListener.onItemClick(itemView, getAdapterPosition());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

// allows clicks events to be caught
void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

// parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}}
```

Comment: I have been using rv for 2 years now, but thanks anyway, I knew the answer, the rep for effort, really appreciated

Comment: Thanks, if you can mark this correct it shall help fellow members in future.

Comment: its not the solution to my problem, I added the solution down there, the issue is: I was making intensive processing and socket communications in the mainThread, so the soln is to transfer those actions into other thread